# Retrieving the last filtered record in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I read a while back this excellent answer by @Bill Karwin:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/317889

This pretty much answers the question however, I have recently had to update my query to filter on the joined tables status.

I have written two queries below, similar to the queries in the post above. The first query which is the slow one works with the joined tables status filtering:

```
SELECT m.*, t1.* FROM mood m 
LEFT JOIN temper t ON ( m._id = t.mood_id ) 
WHERE grantee_username = "username" 
AND m.status_id != 1 // NOT INTERESTED IN THIS FILTER
AND t.status_id != 1 // FILTERING 
GROUP BY m._id;
```

With the second query I have no idea how to add the filtering to get it to work as above:

```
SELECT m.*, t1.* FROM mood m 
LEFT JOIN temper t1 ON ( m._id = t1.mood_id ) 
LEFT JOIN temper t2 ON ( t1.mood_id = t2.mood_id AND t1._id < t2._id ) 
WHERE t2._id IS NULL 
AND m.grantee_username = "username" 
AND m.status_id != 1; // NOT INTERESTED IN THIS FILTER
```

The first query works perfectly but is deemed to be slower than the second query.

The second query works at brining back all mood records with their relating last temper record however that last temper record may have a status of 1 which I don't want.

Any insight would be of interest. I could always just go with the first query but for the sake of performance I would like to figure out how to add the `t.status_id` filtering to the second query if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, works out that it wasn't too dificult after all:

```
SELECT m.*, t1.* FROM mood m 
LEFT JOIN temper t1 ON ( m._id = t1.mood_id AND t1.status_id !=1) 
LEFT JOIN temper t2 ON ( t1.mood_id = t2.mood_id AND t1._id < t2._id AND t2.status_id !=1 ) 
WHERE t2._id IS NULL 
AND m.grantee_username = "username" 
AND m.status_id != 1; // NOT INTERESTED IN THIS FILTER
```

The filter (status_id) needs to be added to each JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second query is missing the GROUP BY at the end.

This version adds the filter in the subquery:

```
SELECT m.*, t1.*
FROM mood m  LEFT JOIN
     (select t.*
      from temper t
      where t.status_id != 1
     ) t1
     ON m._id = t1.mood_id  LEFT JOIN
     temper t2
     ON t1.mood_id = t2.mood_id AND t1._id < t2._id
WHERE t2._id IS NULL AND
      m.grantee_username = "username" 
GROUP BY m._id;
```

Do you also want the filter on t2?

By the way, you are using a feature in MySQl called Hidden Columns -- you are aggregating on one column but returning rows, with no aggregation functions, on other columns.  This feature is only in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the group by should not be needed. It successfully grabs the correct temper record trouble is the last temper record may have a status of 1 which I don't want.

Comment: So I've run your query but the JOIN is not quite working. My test DB has 3 mood records which shoud always be returned which is the case with both of my queries above. Your query returns 1 mood record where the temper status is not 1. Headache!

Comment: Also I'm not sure whether by using a sub select in your query may create a performance difference when comparing to my second query.

Comment: @haraldo ... You are correct.  There are netter performing ways to write this query.  Alas, I'm on amobile device now and can't type it in.